# Como posso obter uma data (dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo) convertidos em milissegundos em Java?

Tags: java, android, datetime

Como posso obter uma data em milissegundos?

Exemplo: 24, Sáb, Jan, 17:39:50 2015

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depende de como você quer usar tem várias maneiras, uma delas pode ser:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date date = sdf.parse("2015-01-24 17:39:50.000");
        System.out.println(date.getTime());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/48uKgM). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FormatSpecific). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/FormatSpecific.java).

Comment: Um detalhe é que `SimpleDateFormat` vai usar o timezone *default* da JVM, então dependendo do que estiver configurado, o valor de `getTime()` pode mudar. Eu coloquei mais detalhes sobre isto na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308438/112052)

Comment: @hkotsubo isso, legal.

Answer (score 6):

A resposta do @Maniero responde diretamente ao que foi perguntado. No entanto, irei acrescentar mais alguns detalhes sobre a questão de milissegundos.

## `Date`

A classe [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) representa internamente a data usando a quantidade de milissegundos passados desde 1 de Janeiro de 1970 UTC (conhecido como *epoch*) num atributo do tipo `long`. Tanto que seu único construtor recomendado recebe justamente o tempo em **ms**.

Exemplo:

```
Date data = new Date(1422279151249l);
```

Mesmo quando usamos o construtor vazio, que cria uma data com a data e hora atuais, na verdade internamente a classe `Date` simplesmente chama o método `System.currentTimeMillis()` para recuperar os milissegundos atuais e repassa ao outro construtor:

```
public Date() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Para recuperar o tempo interno em milissegundos, simplesmente use o método `getTime()`:

```
data.getTime();
```

É possível modificar a data com o método `setTime()`:

```
data.setTime(1422279151249l);
```

Mas isso não é recomendável, pois fere o princípio da imutabilidade do objeto e em alguns casos pode resultar em comportamentos inesperados.

### Convertendo `String` para `Date`

Use a classe `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. Exemplo:

```
Date data = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2015-01-24 17:39:50");
```

## `Calendar`

A classe [java.util.Calendar](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FCalendar.html&ei=tULGVIz_DMebgwSLqoGgBA&usg=AFQjCNFOPahsMxv4McH-tj9xBrWBuuzd9Q&sig2=u2E97W6X1bX4WbisUxjKVQ) é bem diferente de `java.util.Date`. Ela armazena as informações sobre uma data num vetor interno com várias posições, incluindo o fuso horário.

Além disso, a classe `Calendar` é abstrata, pois existem diferentes calendários que a implementam, sendo o mais comum o `GregorianCalendar`.

Para criar uma instância de `Calendar` no tempo atual e com as configurações padrão da sua JVM, basta chamar o método `getInstance` da classe:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Para recuperar o tempo em milissegundos desde o *epoch*, basta usar o método `getTimeInMillis()`:

```
cal.getTimeInMillis()
```

Para alterar o tempo usando milissegundos, use o método *setter* equivalente:

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(1422279151249l);
```

Diferente da classe `Date`, a classe `Calendar` permite facilmente recuperar partes da data. Por exemplo, para recuperar a hora de uma data:

```
int hora = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

Ou para recuperar os milissegundos de uma data:

```
int hora = cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Mas note que o valor retornado não tem anda a ver com o retorno do método `getTimeInMillis`. Enquanto este retorna o número de milissegundos desde o *epoch*, aquele contém o valor dos milissegundos da hora atual, isto é, um número entre `0` e `999`.

Para "converter" um `Date` em `Calendar`, use os métodos `getTime()` e `setTime()`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date data = cal.getTime(); 
cal.setTime(data);
```

### Convertendo `String` para `Calendar`

Conforme a própria documentação já avisa, a classe `Calendar` não possui implementações para converter texto em data ou formatar data em texto.

Portanto, a solução é usar `SimpleDateFormat` para gerar um `Date` e depois passar a informação para o `Calendar`:

```
Date data = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2015-01-24 17:39:50");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(data);
```

## `LocalDateTime` (Java 8)

A partir do Java 8 você deve representar data e hora usando [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). Essa classe é imutável, portanto *thread-safe*, além de muito mais confiável do que as anteriores. Também possui maior precisão, na casa dos nanossegundos.

Para obter a data e hora atuais, use o método *factory* `now()`:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Para obter os milissegundos desde o *epoch*, você pode usar o método `toEpochSecond()` e multiplicar o resultado por `1000`:

```
long ms = 1000 * dateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Por outro lado, para recuperar a quantidade de milissegundos passados desde o último segundo, use o método `get()`:

```
long ms = dateTime.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND);
```

Note que é bem parecido com a classe `Calendar` nesse aspecto.

### Convertendo `String` para `LocalDateTime`

Use a nova classe `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Depois é possível tanto fazer o *parse*:

```
LocalDateTime data = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse("2015-01-24 17:39:50"));
```

Como formatar a data:

```
String dataFormatada = data.format(formatter);
```

Comment: obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: Um detalhe é que `SimpleDateFormat` usa o timezone *default* da JVM e dependendo desta configuração, o valor do timestamp pode mudar. Eu detalho isso na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308438/112052)

Comment: @hkotsubo Boa observação, sempre deve-se informar o timezone quando for possível.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Apenas para complementar, um ponto que não foi abordado nas outras respostas.</sup>

### Timestamp

Conforme a [resposta do @utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48273/112052) explica, o valor que você está pedindo (retornado por [`date.getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--)) é a quantidade de milissegundos desde o Unix Epoch (que é `1970-01-01T00:00Z` - 1 de janeiro de 1970, meia-noite, em [**UTC**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo_Universal_Coordenado)). Este campo [possui muitos nomes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469753) (Unix Time, Unix Timestamp, etc), mas vou chamar apenas de [*timestamp*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) para encurtar.

Um detalhe sobre este número é que ele é o mesmo em todo o mundo.

Por exemplo, se eu rodar agora (neste exato momento em que escrevo), um programa que pega o valor de [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) (um método que retorna o timestamp correspondente à data e hora atual), o resultado será `1529496070462`.

Este valor é o mesmo no mundo todo. Qualquer computador, em qualquer parte do planeta, que rodasse este programa neste mesmo instante, teria esse mesmo resultado.

A diferença é que este mesmo valor pode corresponder a uma data e hora diferente, dependendo do fuso horário em que você está. Abaixo está uma lista com os valores de data e hora, em cada lugar do mundo, que correspondem a este timestamp:

- São Paulo: 20 de junho de 2018, às 09:01:10.462
- Londres: 20 de junho de 2018, às **13**:01:10.462
- Auckland (Nova Zelândia): **21** de junho de 2018, às 00:01:10.462

Repare que em São Paulo e Londres o dia é o mesmo, mas o horário não. E em Auckland, até mesmo o dia é diferente (lá já é dia 21).

Mas todas estas datas e horas correspondem ao **mesmo instante** (ao mesmo ponto na linha do tempo). Em outras palavras, o valor do timestamp é o mesmo.

#### Por que estou falando tudo isso?

Porque a data que você está usando (`24, Sáb, Jan, 17:39:50 2015`) não tem nenhuma informação sobre o fuso horário, então ela pode resultar em um valor de timestamp (o "valor em milissegundos" que você quer) diferente, dependendo do fuso horário que você usa.

A [resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48151/112052) usa [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), e esta classe vai usar o timezone *default* da JVM (o fuso horário padrão que é usado pelo Java quando você não especifica nenhum). E dependendo do que estiver configurado, você pode obter um valor diferente.

Outro detalhe é que, na sua `String`, o dia da semana e mês estão em português, então é importante usar um [`java.util.Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) também. Se você não especificar o locale, o `SimpleDateFormat` vai usar o *default* da JVM, e nem sempre pode ser o idioma que você precisa. Portanto, o código fica assim:

```java
// usar locale pt_BR (português)
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd, EEE, MMM, HH:mm:ss yyyy", new Locale("pt", "BR"));
Date date = sdf.parse("24, Sáb, Jan, 17:39:50 2015");
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

O resultado será `1422128390000`, que é um timestamp que corresponde a 24 de janeiro de 2015, às 17:39:50 em São Paulo. Isso porque o timezone *default* da JVM que estou usando é `America/Sao_Paulo` (você pode ver qual é o seu usando [`TimeZone.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--)).

Mas se eu mudar o timezone *default*, o valor do timestamp será diferente. Exemplo:

```java
// mudando o timezone default
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd, EEE, MMM, HH:mm:ss yyyy", new Locale("pt", "BR"));
Date date = sdf.parse("24, Sáb, Jan, 17:39:50 2015");
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

Eu mudei o timezone *default* para `Asia/Tokyo`, e agora o `SimpleDateFormat` vai usar este timezone para fazer o *parsing* da data. O resultado será `1422088790000`, que corresponde a 24 de janeiro de 2015, às 17:39:50, em Tóquio.
Este mesmo timestamp, em São Paulo, corresponde a 24 de janeiro de 2015, às **06**:39:50 (a diferença não é de 12 horas porque neste dia São Paulo estava em horário de verão).

Ou seja, dependendo do timezone configurado, o `SimpleDateFormat` pode retornar um valor diferente. E confiar na configuração *default* nem sempre é uma boa ideia, já que qualquer ponto do seu sistema pode chamar [`TimeZone.setDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-) (até mesmo outras aplicações rodando na mesma JVM), e isto vai afetar todo o código rodando nesta JVM. Ou o time de infra pode atualizar o servidor e mudar o timezone (de propósito ou sem querer), e não te avisar sobre isso. Enfim, não é algo sobre o qual você tem muito controle.

Por isso, uma alternativa é setar um timezone no próprio `SimpleDateFormat`, e assim você não depende do timezone *default*. Exemplo:

```java
// mudando o timezone default
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd, EEE, MMM, HH:mm:ss yyyy", new Locale("pt", "BR"));
// setar um timezone no SimpleDateFormat, para não depender do default
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
Date date = sdf.parse("24, Sáb, Jan, 17:39:50 2015");
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

Como eu setei o timezone `America/Sao_Paulo` no `SimpleDateFormat`, ele vai usar este timezone para fazer o *parsing*, ignorando o timezone *default*. Por isso o resultado é `1422128390000` (24 de janeiro de 2015, às 17:39:50 em São Paulo).

Se você sabe que aquela data e hora corresponde a um timezone específico, use-o no `SimpleDateFormat`, ao invés de depender da configuração *default* da JVM (que pode mudar sem você perceber).

Se ao invés de um timezone específico, você quiser usar UTC, pode fazer `TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")`.

### Java 8

A partir do Java 8 existe a API [`java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052). Nesta API, a conversão é similar: você precisa saber qual o timezone a ser usado para converter a data e hora para o timestamp.

Primeiro obtemos um [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) (uma classe que possui data e hora). Para isso, usamos um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) para fazer o *parsing*. Aqui, também precisamos usar um `java.util.Locale`, pois o dia da semana e mês estão em português, e é melhor usar um locale específico do que depender da configuração *default* da JVM.

Outro detalhe é que [algumas informações de localização mudaram no Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.8.html), então o mês com letra maiúscula não funcionou no meu teste (**JDK 1.8.0_144**). Por isso, eu também uso um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), que possibilita criar um `DateTimeFormatter` *case insensitive*:

```java
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // ignorar maiúsculas
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    // pattern para data e hora
    .appendPattern("dd, EEE, MMM, HH:mm:ss uuuu")
    // usar locale pt_BR, pois o dia da semana e mês estão em português
    .toFormatter(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("24, Sáb, Jan, 17:39:50 2015", parser);
```

A classe `LocalDateTime` possui apenas a data e hora, sem qualquer noção de fusos horários. Para convertê-la para um timezone, eu preciso usar um [`java.time.ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html), e em seguida eu uso o resultado para obter o valor do timestamp:

```java
long timestamp = dateTime
    // converte para um timezone
    .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"))
    // obtém o timestamp em milissegundos
    .toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Como eu escolhi o timezone `America/Sao_Paulo`, o valor do timestamp será `1422128390000` (pois corresponde a 24 de janeiro de 2015, às 17:39:50 em São Paulo).

Se você quiser outro timezone, basta mudar o nome passado para [`ZoneId.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-). Prefira sempre os nomes no [padrão da IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (no formato "Continente/Região", como `America/Sao_Paulo`, `Europe/London`, etc). Você pode usar o método [`ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds--), que retorna todos os nomes válidos.

Caso você escolha usar o timezone *default* da JVM, use [`ZoneId.systemDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--). Lembrando de todos os cuidados já citados acima, sobre o fato do timezone *default* poder ser mudado sem você perceber.

E para usar UTC, use a constante [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

#### Usar `java.time` em versões anteriores ao Java 8

Para JDK 6 e 7, existe o [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), que é um backport do `java.time`. Este backport contém as mesmas classes do Java 8 (com os mesmos nomes, métodos e funcionamento).

A diferença é que, em vez de estarem no pacote `java.time`, estão no pacote `org.threeten.bp`. Mas o modo de usar será o mesmo explicado acima.

Eu recomendo usar estas opções (`java.time` para JDK >= 8 e ThreeTen Backport para JDK 6 e 7), pois é uma API muito superior à `Date`, `Calendar` e `SimpleDateFormat` (que possuem [muitos problemas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265) e [decisões de design questionáveis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442) - motivos que levaram à criação de uma nova API de datas).

#### Joda-Time

Em [seu próprio site](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/#Support), o Joda-Time recomenda que se use o `java.time`:

> *Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310).*
>
> Tradução livre: "Note que o Joda-Time é considerado um projeto 'encerrado'. Não há melhorias planejadas. Se estiver usando Java SE 8, por favor migre para o `java.time` (JSR-310)."

De qualquer forma, é uma alternativa para quem ainda estiver preso ao JDK 5 e quer usar algo melhor que `Date` e `Calendar` ([veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/413649/112052) uma discussão mais detalhada, aí você pode decidir melhor se vai usá-lo ou não). O funcionamento é parecido com o `java.time`: fazer *parsing*, converter para um timezone e obter o timestamp.

Algumas classes tem o mesmo nome de classes do `java.time`, mas elas ficam no pacote `org.joda.time`, e além disso, [elas não são exatamente iguais](http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html).

```java
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd, EEE, MMM, HH:mm:ss yyyy")
    // usar locale pt_BR, pois o dia da semana e mês estão em português
    .withLocale(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
LocalDateTime dateTime = parser.parseLocalDateTime("24, Sáb, Jan, 17:39:50 2015");
long timestamp = dateTime
    // converter para um timezone
    .toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo"))
    // obter o timestamp
    .getMillis();
```

Comment: Sobre o java-8 também há uma wiki no site sobre ela: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177129/como-migrar-de-date-e-calendar-para-a-nova-api-de-datas-no-java-8

Comment: @Articuno Sim, eu vi. Só quis dar uma solução usando a API do java.time, já que as outras respostas não fazem o *parsing* da `String` que está na pergunta (e aproveitei para colocar mais detalhes também).

Comment: Sim, foi só complementar mesmo(e pra ficar referenciado na lista lateral) o meu comentário, sua resposta vai muito além de apenas falar do java-8 :)

Answer (score 1):

Quer somente o milissegundo? Use o java.sql.Timestamp:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class DateTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}
```

---

Se você quiser TUDO, pode utilizar o Joda e você pode fazer isso em três linhas:

(http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

```
DateTime jodaTime = new DateTime();

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.println("jodaTime = " + formatter.print(jodaTime));
```

Você também tem acesso direto aos campos individuais da data sem o uso de um calendário.

```
System.out.println("year = " + jodaTime.getYear());
System.out.println("month = " + jodaTime.getMonthOfYear());
System.out.println("day = " + jodaTime.getDayOfMonth());
System.out.println("hour = " + jodaTime.getHourOfDay());
System.out.println("minute = " + jodaTime.getMinuteOfHour());
System.out.println("second = " + jodaTime.getSecondOfMinute());
System.out.println("millis = " + jodaTime.getMillisOfSecond());
```

Saída :)

```
jodaTime = 2010-04-16 18:09:26.060

year = 2010
month = 4
day = 16
hour = 18
minute = 9
second = 26
millis = 60 **O QUE VOCÊ PEDIU NO COMENTÁRIO**
```

Ou use o java.util.Calendar.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH); // Note: zero based!
int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int millis = now.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

System.out.printf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", year, month + 1, day, hour, minute, second, millis);
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654025/how-to-get-year-month-day-hours-minutes-seconds-and-milliseconds-of-the-cur

Comment: Mesmo não sendo respondida a minha questão, essas passagens serviram para construir a minha resposta. Obrigado ;)